Is it possible to pass Basic Auth credentials to apt-get as command line arguments?
I use Alt Linux 10.2. The only way to store Basic Auth credentials supported here is to write them directly to the sources.list file:
rpm [p10] http://login:password@somerepo.com x86_64 classic

In the project I work to, the credentials are stored in some utility (suppose it's called credmaster). I need to hide my credentials as far as possible so just write them to sources.list is not possible. One of idea is to replace apt-get with a wrapper script that would obtain credentials before calling apt-get and pass them to it. Something like that:
LOGIN=$(credmaster --login)
PSWD=$(credmaster --password)
apt-get -o 'BasicAuthCred=somerepo.url:$LOGIN:$PSWD' update
...

I tried the approach with Dir::Etc::netrc option but it did not work out (I guess apt version is too old).
Is there another way or workaround to pass Basic Auth credentials to apt-get without need to store them in file?

According to man apt_auth.conf in Debian 12, the basic support for using  /etc/apt/auth.conf (the default file for Dir::Etc::netrc) existed since apt version 0.7.25, but undocumented. The implementation was changed a bit in version 1.5, and it was also documented at that time. I could not easily find out which version of apt is in Alt Linux 10.2, but I'd be surprised if it's older than 0.7.25.

Also, note that any command line arguments tend to be visible to all users in ps -ef listings (using PID namespaces may change that, but the initial namespace will still see everything).

@telcoM I had asked Alt Linux maintainers about apt_auth.conf, they answered me apt version is 0.5.15.
BTW thanks for noting about ps -ef, it really matters.

Wow. Well, I guess Alt Linux has their reasons for staying with such an old version of apt.
